# DRF - MultiPartParse during post request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to DRF, I am working on a personal project, that consists of an API (DRF) and a front (React). On the front, there will be a form that allows to input some fields (Author, year...), and send a bunch of images together with it.

I have two *models* that look roughly like this

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    ...

class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

Serializers are already created, everything works fine if I upload first images, and then (for instance, on the Django portal), create the Data with the image IDs, but I would like to **send only one request from the front, with data and files**, and handle all the operations on the server side (instead of sending images one by one, and then making a second request)

So, on my **views.py**, I created one method that handles POST and GET of Data, on the POST part, my intention is to create the following

```
 elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = MultiPartParser().parse(request.data)

    images = []
    for image in data.files:
        new_Image = Image(image, ...)
        new_Image.save()
        images.append(new_Image)

    data = Data(data.author, ...)
    data.images.add(images)
    serializer = DataSerializer(data, many=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I have **two problems**,
First, the multipartparser does not work for me, it gives me error all the time on Keyerror 'request'
Second, it acts in a funny way, **MultiPartParser().parse(...) is called twice**, first from *_parser* (which honestly I don't know where it comes from) and then from *my method*. The first one does not raise any errors, and has all the proper information from the request (data and files), the second one, the one I make, is the one that gives me that error.

What am I doing wrong? I did not use the usual format of class viewsets.ModelViewSet, since I want to learn things more in-depth (for instance, made the pagination myself for the GET Data), should I do things differently? Is there a better approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `Image` here? can you add complete view code?

Comment: Image in this case comes from the models.py, the first chunk of code posted.

I have been able to solve this situation in a different way, I will post it later today. Thanks in any case!